# XSLT Merge nodes subelements by same key value

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, nodes

I have an xml like this.

```
<root>
<field1>__<field1/>
<field2>__<field2/>
<list>
    <sublist1>
        <key>AAA</key>
        <field4>__</field4>
    </sublist1>
    <sublist1>
    <sublist1>
        <key>BBB</key>
        <field4>__</field4>
    </sublist1>
    <sublist2>
        <key>AAA</key>
        <field6>__<field6/>
    </sublist2>
    <sublist2>
        <key>BBB</key>
        <field6>__<field6/>
    </sublist2>
</list>
```

I need merge the sublist1 with the respective sublist2 based on the value of element key. The expected output is the following.

```
<root>
<field1>__</field1>
<field2>__</field2>
<list>
    <mergedSublist>
        <key>AAA</key>
        <field4>__</field4>
        <field6>__</field6>
    </mergedSublist>
    <mergedSublist>
        <key>BBB</key>
        <field4>__</field4>
        <field6>__</field6>
    </mergedSublist>
</list>
```

How can I achieve this with xslt?

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? Should be rather simple to achieve using a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key).

Comment: What version of XSLT? If >= 2.0, look at [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group). If 1.0, take a look at [muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: I renamed all the sublist* into sublist. Now if I use the following, it produces 4 mergedSublist instead of 2. <xsl:template match="/">      
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="root/list/sublist" group-by="key">
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. Note that if the input has only `sublist1` and `sublist2` then no grouping is necessary. Simply process `sublist1`  and use a key to add the field from the corresponding  `sublist2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using xsl:for-each-group...

**XML Input** (fixed to be well-formed)

```
<root>
    <field1>__</field1>
    <field2>__</field2>
    <list>
        <sublist1>
            <key>AAA</key>
            <field4>__</field4>
        </sublist1>
        <sublist1>
            <key>BBB</key>
            <field4>__</field4>
        </sublist1>
        <sublist2>
            <key>AAA</key>
            <field6>__</field6>
        </sublist2>
        <sublist2>
            <key>BBB</key>
            <field6>__</field6>
        </sublist2>
    </list>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="key">
        <mergedSublist>          
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key,current-group()/*[not(self::key)]"/>
        </mergedSublist>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <field1>__</field1>
   <field2>__</field2>
   <list>
      <mergedSublist>
         <key>AAA</key>
         <field4>__</field4>
         <field6>__</field6>
      </mergedSublist>
      <mergedSublist>
         <key>BBB</key>
         <field4>__</field4>
         <field6>__</field6>
      </mergedSublist>
   </list>
</root>
```

If you have any questions on what the XSLT is doing, let me know and I'll add further details.

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBm/1

Comment: Trying to understand your answer, what does <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> do? The nodes do not contain attributes.

Comment: @Sebastien - With your sample XML it's not necessary and could be removed. I usually base new templates on the identity transform and didn't remove it just in case attributes might be present on `list`.

Comment: `current-group()[1]/key` can be shortened to `key`, as the first item in the group is the context item inside the `for-each-group`.